# All possible change combinations

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to output a list of lists with all possible combinations of change given an amount and coins.
For example - given the amount 6 and the coins = [1,5,10] I would get:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,5],
[5,1]]
```

I wrote something that prints the correct solution but I cannot figure out how to get the function to output the solutions in a list of lists format

```
def possible_change(n,p=[],coins = [1,5,10]):
    if n == 0:
        print(p)
        return p
    else:
        for c in coins:
            if n - c >= 0:
                possible_change(n-c,p+[c],coins=coins)

possible_change(6,coins=[1,5,10])
```

How to I get the function to return the actual lists?

Comment: You could make a global list and append to it rather than printing.  I would consider it better to make a class that has the list as an attribute and the function as a method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of those print statements, simply populate a global list.

```
sols = []
def possible_change(n,p=[],coins = [1,5,10]):
    if n == 0:
        global sols
        sols.append(p)
    else:
        for c in coins:
            if n - c >= 0:
                possible_change(n-c,p+[c],coins=coins)    

possible_change(6,coins=[1,5,10])
print(sols)
```

`[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a total list to the function and return it if the n - c is less then 0 or if the `for loop for c in coins:` is end

```
def possible_change(n,p=[],coins = [1,5,10], total=[]):
    if n == 0:
        total.append(p)
    else:
        for c in coins:
            if n - c >= 0:
                print("c {}".format(c))
                possible_change(n-c,p+[c],coins=coins)
            else:
                return total
    return total

print(possible_change(6,coins=[1,5,10]))
```

Result

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 1]]
```